# How does PHP evaluate compound if statements?

Tags: php

Given the nested if statements below:

```
if(file_exists($fullPathToSomeFile)) {
    if(is_readable($fullPathToSomeFile)) {
        include($fullPathToSomeFile);
    }
}
```

how does this differ from:

```
if(file_exists($fullPathToSomeFile) &&  is_readable($fullPathToSomeFile)) {
    include($fullPathToSomeFile);
}
```

Specifically, I want to know how PHP will treat is_readable() if $fullPathToSomeFile does not exist (first conditional fails).

At some point, I started nesting these because using the one-liner version was throwing errors under some conditions. It seems to me that using any 'and' will ask PHP to evaluate everything regardless of the true / false result.

What I really want is to have it stop evaluating when it reaches the first false, thereby preventing warnings or fatal errors when the conditional fails. Doing it nested (first example) guarantees this, but nested if statements are harder to read and maintain.

What's the current best practice for handling this?

Comment: As far as the `include` statement is concerned, they're not different. Both `if` statements need to be true. Where it's different is if you want to have logic that relies on the file existing, but not necessarily if it's readable.

Comment: if `file_exists` fails - there's no need to check `is_readable` because in this case the result will __NEVER__ be true.

Comment: @u_mulder That's not true. The file could exist but perms could disallow its being read.

Comment: @Blake - that's the exist case I am considering. But, in conditions where the file doesn't exist, is_readable() is moot. If they are in the one-liner version, will it still be evaluated (and thereby throw errors) or will it terminate the if at the first false?

Comment: @Blake read question again - `if $fullPathToSomeFile does not exist `

Comment: What would you do if you were a human?

If milk_jug_in_fridge & milk_jun_has_milk, drink.

If there's no milk jug in the fridge, you can't drink the milk.  So by logic the file has to exist (be true) before it'll continue to the next item.

Comment: According to the docs for `is_readable()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-readable.php -- `"Tells whether a file exists and is readable."` -- Why duplicate the functionality? `Returns TRUE if the file or directory specified by filename exists and is readable, FALSE otherwise.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Specifically, I want to know how PHP will treat is_readable() if $fullPathToSomeFile does not exist (first conditional fails).

PHP uses  [short-circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) for the `&&` operator. That is, if the first condition in an expression like `if (A && B)` fails, it is obvious the the whole condition will be false. Thus, the second condition B does not need to be evaluated to determine the result and will not be evaluated at all.

Take for example the following code:

```
<?php
  function hey()
  {
    echo "Hey there!\n";
    return true;
  }

  if (false && hey())
  {
    echo "Statement evaluated to true.\n";
  }
  else
  {
    echo "Statement evaluated to false.\n";
  }
?>
```

This will echo only one line ("Statement evaluated to false."), but not "Hey there!", because the second part of the if condition will not be evaluated.

Comment: This is what I thought (based on the first example in the PHP manual), but the example in the manual is rather unclear. Thanks!